# what is the .exe for JIT debugger?

Tags: debugging, jit

What is the executable for JIT debugger called? Trying to get it elevated at work but can't seem to figure out what the .exe for it is.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it. `vsjitdebugger.exe` is the name of the executable, which kicks off and eventually launches visual studio.